# checking a variable in python if valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python code and clearIsAdmin fails is always printed.
cleanIsAdmin is true and the lowercase is valid as well.

```
        cleanIsAdmin = 'true'

        if (cleanIsAdmin is not None) and (cleanIsAdmin.islower() == 'true'):
            print("cleanIsAdmin passes")
        else:
            print("clearIsAdmin fails")
```

what is wrong here please. why is "cleanIsAdmin fails" always printed ?

Comment: You're using `islower` instead of `lower`

Comment: I would convert `cleanIsAdmin` to a proper `bool` first, *then* just use `if cleanIsAdmin: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
cleanIsAdmin = 'true'

# updated first conditional based on comments
if cleanIsAdmin and (cleanIsAdmin.lower() == 'true'):
        print("cleanIsAdmin passes")
else:
        print("clearIsAdmin fails")
```

`str.islower()` returns a bool, which in this case would be `True`, not the string `"true"`. `str.lower()` will make the string lowercase.

Comment: `if (cleanIsAdmin is not None)` can just be shortened to `if cleanIsAdmin` it does the same check.

Comment: This doesn't handle `cleanIsAdmin = None` correctly.